# Conditional panel message flashes and then disappears when initializing app

Tags: shiny

When I run the below app, the red message in the conditional panel statement flashes and disappears. Can someone explain why, and how to remove it?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Choose a number",1.1,1,10),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.square",
    div("That's a perfect square!",style="color:red; height:400px")
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$square <- reactive({
    sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'square', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Maybe because you don't have a condition in `condition = `

Comment: Don’t think this is required.

Comment: @roccomay below please find a UI-only (not using `renderUI`) solution.

Comment: @novica your guess is correct - please see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Updated revised answer**

Before addressing to the actual problem of the flashing red message:

Formerly, I thought the problem is related to the fact that output (`output$square`) is defined as reactive. I thought that this would not work and that it would be causing the error. However, although this is definitely not how shiny is intended to be used (`reactive`s represent 'reactive conductors' whereas `output`s represent 'reactive endpoints'), your approach seems to be working.

A more shiny-like way of rebuilding your approach could make use of renderUI. Below, I intentionally included an (intermediate) reactive.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Choose a number",1.1,1,10),
  uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  square_out <- reactive({
    sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0
  })

  output$text <- renderUI({

    if (square_out()) {
      div("That's a perfect square!",style="color:red; height:400px")
    }

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

This reactive leads to the very same flashing message in the beginning. The reason is that when starting the app, the reactive is not yet evaluated, that is in R it is NULL. In javascript this translates to:

```
toJSON(NULL)
> {}
```

This is an empty condition which is equivalent to `true`. So the message is displayed. Then, the reactive is evaluated and the condition kicks in, hiding the message.

So a better way would be to use Gregs approach and put the condition in the `renderUI` statement (see his answer). Here the UI element is only displayed when evaluated, and while evaluating the condition is checked. Here it is not possible that the UI element is shown while the part generating the condition is not executed/evaluated yet.

So my second approach also is no help in getting rid of the flashing message. Here the idea was to generate a `textOutput` and use it as condition of the conditional panel, however, the same problem arises as with the reactive: in the beginning it is not yet evaluated and the red message appears.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  numericInput("num", "Choose a number",1.1,1,10),

  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.text == 'TRUE'",
    div("That's a perfect square!",style="color:red; height:400px")
  ),
  textOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$text <- renderText({
    print(sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0)
    sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0

  })

}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

I hope this sheds some light on the issue.

Answer (score 2):

I ran into the same problem some time ago and got it [answered on GitHub](https://github.com/rstudio/shiny/issues/3505#issuecomment-922211210).

When calling a `conditionalPanel` a `div` tag is created. This `div` tag by default is visible - once the condition is checked it's hidden.

To hide it right from the start we can add a style attribute setting `display: none;` for `conditionalPanel` (Please see the example below).

I'd prefer `conditionalPanel` over `renderUI` as we avoid the time consuming detour to the server.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Choose a number", 1.1, 1, 10),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.square",
    div("That's a perfect square!", style = "color:red; height:400px;"),
    style = "display: none;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$square <- reactive({
    sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'square', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

---

**Edit:** Another option to avoid the flashing is using a "proper" conditional statement like `output.square == true`.

The reason for this is given [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Boolean):

> Any object of which the value is not undefined or null, including a
> Boolean object whose value is false, evaluates to true when passed to
> a conditional statement.

Accordingly as soon as `output.square` is not null the condition evaluates to true.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
  numericInput("num", "Choose a number", 1.1, 1, 10),
  conditionalPanel(
    condition = "output.square == true",
    div("That's a perfect square!", style = "color:red; height:400px;"),
    style = "display: none;"
  )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  output$square <- reactive({
    sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'square', suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Answer (score 1):

The code below has the same functionality but removes the conditional panel flash - does that work for you or do you need to use `conditionalPanel`?

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(
    numericInput("num", "Choose a number",
                 value = 1.1,
                 min = 1,
                 max = 10),
    uiOutput("text")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

output$text <- renderUI({
    if(sqrt(as.numeric(input$num)) %% 1 == 0){
        div("That's a perfect square!",style="color:red; height:400px")
    }
    else{
        div("",style="color:red; height:400px")
    }
})
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I am upvoting your answer as it solves the problem, but listing the other answer is a bit more in-depth on why it works, so I am selecting this as the question answer.